# How to stop a program in production safely

Tags: linux, python-3.x, server, rabbitmq, continuous-deployment

We have multiple machines running as "servers". On them, they have a program that listen to requests from different clients.

In part of a continuous deployment process, updating the servers program can cause unfinished business to be killed. This is undesirable. I'm looking for an approach to drain the work from one node so we can update it while the other gets the load.

As for a more specific question representing my current mindset :

How do you send a "signal" so :

```
while True and no_signal:
    do_server_work()
```

stops if we need to upgrade it.

For our infrastructure, we have many clients sending request to multiple RabbitMQ nodes where servers consume their queues.

Edit : On linux, using python3

Comment: Who is coding that program? Are you allowed and capable of improving it?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed to do whatever is needed.

Comment: You're asking a very abstract question about a very specific problem. Can you add clarifying details or constraints so that we may guide you to an answer? For example, RabbitMQ is tagged, and has the "cancel consumer" function, but it is unclear how or even if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Well, it's abstract for a reason. I'm looking for different approaches. To cancel consumer was something i didn't know from RabbitMQ. That would have been a possible good answer. I don't need actual code.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(I guess you are on Linux, or at least on POSIX machines)</sup>

For *well-written* server programs, you should send them a `SIGTERM` signal (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for details) to terminate them gently, and they should *explicitly* (and *cleverly*) handle that signal. A common way to do so is to use the [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) program (or the underlying [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call).

Badly written server programs might not handle `SIGTERM` as they should. Then (a few seconds later) you might need to kill them with `SIGKILL`, but that could leave them (or their files) in some inconsistent state, since `SIGKILL` cannot be caught.

Some server programs are documented to behave differently. For example, they might use some other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facility to be asked to to terminate gently.

Handling `SIGTERM` properly is a widely used *convention* (but read also [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) if you are coding a server handling it). Some servers might have a different one.

BTW, there are several tricks to write *safe* signal handlers (read carefully [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) at the C level. One is to have a global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable that is set by your signal handler, and tested *regularly* in your code (perhaps in your [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)). Another is to set up (at initialization, using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)) a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self, to have your signal handler [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) one or a few bytes into it (this is legal, since [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is an async-signal-safe function) and to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) that pipe in your event loop. The later trick is common enough to be [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) in Qt.

Probably, Python handles [signals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) using the first trick or something similar (perhaps related to its infamous [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). Since it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could study its source code (right now, I am too lazy for that).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out how to catch an exception raised from a SIGTERM so I can finish the jobs even if it comes at anytime. Good point, I'm looking at that approach as we speak.

Comment: `SIGTERM` is *not* an exception, but a [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)). Exceptions are either at the hardware level (e.g. page fault, privileged instruction, division by zero) or in a language runtime (and these are *two different meanings* of the "exception" word).

Comment: I was refering to Python ways to handle a Ctrl+C during program execution. You are right. I'm reading about signals and how to implement them. It seems like a good plan.

Comment: Ctrl-C is *usually* sending a `SIGINT`, not a `SIGTERM`